# How to add new jar file to existing deployed jar in server

Tags: java, deployment, jar, shared-libraries

I have a RMI application which is running on the server. Now i want to add external jar file to an existing deployed jar.

Note: It is not web application.

For example, here i mention the jar directories

MyApplication.jar

- manifest.mf
- .classpath
- classes

  - My java class files
- lib

  - test.jar
  - test1.jar
- images
- META-INF

  - MANIFEST.MF

.classpath has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Now i want to add test2.jar to my lib folder inside MyApplication.jar and updating .classpath file.

Is it possible to add it?

Comment: A jar can not include jar files as i know.

Comment: i don't think this is possible to do without restarting. Make your replacements, modify the .classpath , and then runt the jar again.

Comment: @Adriaan: I have to use only freeware plugins if necessary.

Comment: @jens: Yes, a jar can not include jar files but using one-jar i can build single jar with libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) then you will probably have to try to write your own class loader to achieve this. There are many pitfalls. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22805094/181336) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913149/hot-swapping-the-jar-files-in-java) for some pointers.